# Stuck on Induction Hypothesis, I don't know how to continue

Tags: calculus, summation, proof-writing, induction, geometric-series

I would like to prove the following proposition by induction:

> For all $m\in\mathbb N$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{i}{2^i} = 2 - \frac{m+2}{2^m}.$

First, I prove the base step $m = 1$:

$\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{i}{2^i} = 2 - \frac{3}{2}.$, which is effectively $\frac{1}{2}$ on both sides of this equation.

Next, I assume that there is some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{2^i} = 2 - \frac{k+2}{2^{k}}.
$$

Now, to prove the inductive step I do: (I cannot put the 2nd 2k as 2^k+1)
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{i}{2^i}= 2 - \frac{k+2}{2^k}+ \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}
$$

I don't know what to do at this point as I cross multiply them, they decide to not work past that point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the right hand side :

$$2 - \frac{k+2}{2^k}+ \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} = 2 + \frac{-2(k+2)+k+1}{2^{k+1}} = 2-\frac{(k+1)+2}{2^{k+1}} $$

which is your proposition in the $k+1$-th case.

Comment: I see, but the only thing I'm confused about is the 2nd step here. How did you get the denominator to be kept as $2^{k+1}$ @Tortar. Oh is it because 2 acted as the (+1) portion?

Comment: you must just sum the two fractions , try to do it this way gather $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ then you will have $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} ( -2(k+2)+k+1)$ , or try to come back from the result $\frac{(-2(k+2))+(k+1)}{2^{k+1}}$ to the previous step dividing the two parts

Comment: I don't get really well what you mean by 'Oh is it because 2 acted as the (+1) portion?'

Comment: Oh, I somewhat get it. By that statement, since we know $2^{k+1}$ is what is it, it can be broken down to 2^k * 2. Hence, why I thought you multiplied two there.

Comment: yes that's why I multiplied the first part of numerator!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I keep forgetting statements like that can be used the way that you demonstrated. Thank you, you just made my understanding much more clearer

Comment: Glad to having helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way.

Put
$$S_m=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{i}{2^i}=2-\frac{m+2}{2^m}$$

You just need, for the inductive step, to prove that

$$S_{m+1}-S_m=\color{red}{\frac{m+1}{2^{m+1}}}$$

but

$$S_{m+1}-S_m=$$
$$(2-\frac{m+3}{2^{m+1}})-(2-\frac{m+2}{2^m})=$$

$$\frac{m+2}{2^m}-\frac{m+3}{2^{m+1}}=$$

$$\frac{2m+4-m-3}{2^{m+1}}=$$
$$\color{red}{\frac{m+1}{2^{m+1}}}$$
Done.